# How to hide ActiveMQ broker version in STOMP CONNECTED server header?

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp, owasp

I want to fulfill [OWASP ASVS 14.3.3](https://github.com/OWASP/ASVS/blob/master/4.0/en/0x22-V14-Config.md#v143-unintended-security-disclosure-requirements) requirement, which stands:

> 14.3.3 Verify that the HTTP headers or any part of the HTTP response do not expose detailed version information of system components.

For ActiveMQ broker.
I have a problem with `STOMP` protocol `CONNECTED` message which looks like this:

```
CONNECTED
server:ActiveMQ/5.15.9
heart-beat:0,10000
session:ID:localhost.local-36323-1578488170638-3:15
version:1.2
user-name:user@example.com
```

And reveal(to hypothetical evil one) my `ActiveMQ` broker version
So my question is how to hide whole `server` header or if it is not possible maybe its version part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by little hacking

1. As header `server` is set by constant `BROKER_VERSION` in code
   [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/activemq-5.15.11/activemq-stomp/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/stomp/ProtocolConverter.java#L791)
2. And the value of constant `BROKER_VERSION` is read [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/activemq-5.15.11/activemq-stomp/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/stomp/ProtocolConverter.java#L89) from classpath location `/org/apache/activemq/version.txt`
3. We have to override the content of `/org/apache/activemq/version.txt` which surprisingly reside in activemq-client